# Extract value from XML

Tags: bash, sed, xml

I have this XML:

```
<results><testsuites><testcase name="XXXX (XXXXX)" time="20.3817"><result>success</result></testcase><total_time value="20.3830" /></testsuites></results>
```

I want to extract  the 20.3817.

Trying some sed but not getting to work.

Comment: How would you like to do this? You tagged your Q `sed`, please include what you already tried.

Comment: Can you provide a second sample input and output? Just as one cannot extrapolate a line from a single data point, we cannot tell what you need from a single example.

Comment: `sed "s:/.*/20.3817/g"`

Answer (score 9):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML. Use an XML aware tool, e.g. `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(/results/testsuites/testcase/@time)' file.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

With [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//testcase/@time' -nl data.xml
20.3817
```

Comment: Damn, that's a great tool! I need to work with xml files from the command line and appending multiple -`v <xpath>` args to print everything in a single line is just what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Use lxprintf:

```
lxprintf -e "%s\n" total_time/@value test.xml
```

Comment: When can I find this `lxprintf` command?  (Either a link, or the relevant package name in a common distro will suffice.)  Also, your answer looks like it will print "20.3830", not the OP's requested "20.3817".

Answer (score 1):

`perl` has a nice XML parse in `XML::Twig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all'; 

use XML::Twig;

print XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA ) -> get_xpath('//total_time',0)->att('value');

__DATA__
<results><testsuites><testcase name="XXXX (XXXXX)" time="20.3817"><result>success</result></testcase><total_time value="20.3830" /></testsuites></results>
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Twig -ne 'print XML::Twig -> parse (<>) -> get_xpath('//total_time',0)->att('value')'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You would be far, far better using an XML-aware tool**

If it really is a simple case of extracting the value of the `time` attribute you can use `sed`. As you'll see from most of the answers here the better approach really is to use a tool that understands XML, but for really simple cases you *might get away with* using `sed`.

```
xml='<results><testsuites><testcase name="XXXX (XXXXX)" time="20.3817"><result>success</result></testcase><total_time value="20.3830" /></testsuites></results>'
echo "$xml" | sed -nr 's/.* time="([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'    # GNU
28.3817
echo "$xml" | sed -n 's/.* time="\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'   # Non-GNU
28.3817
```

Or `grep`

```
echo "$xml" | grep -Po '(?<=time=")([0-9.]+)'          # GNU
20.3817
```

But **I'd still prefer something XML-aware like `xmlstarlet`**, which can recognise `time` as an attribute of `<testcase>`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I wouldn't even suggest using `sed`, for all the reasons I wouldn't suggest trying to put a screw in the wall with a hammer. Whilst it might technically work, it will always be a bodge and produce messy, if technically functional solutions.

Comment: @Sobrique I'm with you. However, it is possible the OP is running on a system that doesn't have (cannot have) a sensible way of parsing the XML. So for them, or for a potential future reader in that position, I'd like to offer the `sed` and `grep` options. I think I've added enough caveats to the suggestions (although I suppose I ought to rewrite the `sed` to avoid the GNU extensions...).

Answer (score 0):

With `xidel`:

```
$ xidel -e '//testcase/@time' file
20.3830
```